# Let $f: \Bbb{R^n} \rightarrow \Bbb{R}$ be a function such that $\forall q \in \Bbb{Q}$, the sublevel set $\{x: f(x)<q\}$ is open...

Tags: real-analysis

This is a question in old qualification exam. Given the condition mentioned by the title, I am asked:

a) Must $f$ be Borel-measurable?
b) Must $f$ be continuous?

First, I know that b) is true since every set $\{f < \alpha\}$ can be expressed as countable union of $\{f < q_i\}$ where $\{q_i\}$ is a sequence of rational numbers that converges to $\alpha$. I am not sure how to answer a). More specifically, what does it mean to be "Borel-measurable?" It certainly means that measure is defined on Borel sets, but I can't go any further at this point.

Comment: Use ```$\Bbb{R^n}$ and $\Bbb{Q}$``` for the set of real numbers and rational numbers otherwise it is confusing

Comment: Any continuous function from $\mathbb R^{n}$ to $\mathbb R$ is Borel measurable.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy In order to show that $f$ is Borel measurable, what are the things that I need to show? Am I required to show: 1. $\forall F \subset \mathbb R$ Borel, $f^{-1}(F) \subset \mathbb R^n$ is Borel? or 2. $\forall E \subset \mathbb R^n$ Borel, $f(E) \subset \mathbb R$ is measurable? I am just confused what I am supposed to show.

Comment: First one is the right one.

Comment: I see. So really, it suffices to show that $\forall U \subset \mathbb R^1$ open, $f^{-1}(U)$ is a Borel set (or is an open set). Is this correct?

Comment: The function $f(x) = 1_{[0,1]}(x)$ satisfies the condition but b) is clearly not true.

Comment: @copper.hat I see. I was mixed up between continuity and measurability. What I have shown is measurability of $f$. But the same argument nonetheless applies to prove part a).